# Alternate method for clearing input buffer in c

Tags: c

Is there any other method to clear the input buffer in c withut using

```
  fflush();
```

or

```
  while(getchar()!='\n');
```

Because i have read it everywhere and cant find any other way to do it.

Comment: How about `while (scanf("%c",&c) == 1)`?

Comment: @barakmanos sorry sir, but din't you mean `while (scanf("%c",&c) == 1);`?

Comment: `rewind(stdin);` and `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` might work although i've not tested it...

Comment: Yeah, well, you'd be better off with the `;`...

Comment: What is the use-case where you need something other than this?

Comment: what is worng with fflush(stdin)?

Comment: @JonatanGoebel , [Using `fflush` on stdin is Undefined Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: **No** `stdin = 0`, **man fflush: "If the stream argument is NULL, fflush() flushes all open output streams."** So `fflush(stdin)` - flushes all open output streams and has nothing to do with the input buffer.

Comment: Fflush() is not recommended in the documentation nd that while method sometimes results in a loop if not placed at the right place . i hope it helps

Comment: How about `__fpurge(stdin)` ?, defined in `#include <stdio_ext.h>`, I say [`__fpurge()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge) and not `fpurge()` since the former is present in `glibc`, the latter isn't. Both are non-standard functions. Its worked quite well for me so far, however I'm not aware of its drawback, can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to not depend on the input buffer's state so much.

Read input as whole lines, using `fgets()`, then parse those. Don't use e.g. `scanf()` to read individual values, since it interacts with the buffer in annoying ways.

Comment: But i m talking about the case eg when using getchar( ) some "/n " or other characters which have not been read interferes with the functioning .using fgets() or getline() is another issue thanks for the reply though .

Answer (score 2):

Another method to clear the input buffer (`stdin`) would be to use

```
scanf("%*[^\n]");
scanf("%*c");
```

`%*[^\n]` instructs `scanf` to scan everything until a new-line character(`\n`) and then discards it. The `%*c` tells `scanf` to scan and discard a single character which in this case will be the newline character.

Comment: `flushstdin.c:9:5: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘*’ in format [-Wformat=]`

Comment: "Here, `%*[^\n]` instructs `scanf` to scan everything until a new-line character(\n) is found and then discard it." is not true if the first `char` is `'\n'`.  `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

Comment: Using `%*c` instead of `%*1[\n]` does not solve the problem when input is only `'\n'` as that 2nd part of the format specifier is not reached.  Instead code code code use 2 independent `scanf()` calls: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*1[\n]");` or `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();`.

Comment: @chux ,Isn't the `%` at the end of `scanf("%*[^\n]%");` a typo? Anyway,Thanks for making me understand!

Answer (score 2):

Using `fgets()` as suggester [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273595/2410359) best approach.

To flush to the end of the line.

```
void FlushStdin(void) {
  int ch;
  while(((ch = getchar()) !='\n') && (ch != EOF));
}
```

If `stdin` is all ready flushed to the end-of-line, calling `FlushStdin()` or other posted `scanf()`, `fgetc()` solutions, will flush to the end of the *next* line.

Note `scanf("%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");` does *not* work if the next `char` is `'\n'`.