# Infinite loop when trying to clear the input buffer

Tags: c

OK so after reading these previous questions:

[Alternate method for clearing input buffer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273303/alternate-method-for-clearing-input-buffer-in-c)

[How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

I came up with a piece of code to empty the input buffer and count how many values were in the buffer, then return this number. A comparison is then made to check if the number exceeded the allowed number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int Empty();
int main()
{
    double x;
    int y=0;
    while(y==0)
    {
        y=1;

        if(scanf("%lf",&x)!=1 || Empty()>1) //checks if the value is acceppted
                                           // and then attempts to empty
                                           // the input buffer. I always expect 
                                          //at least 1 returned due to the 
                                          // EOF or '\n'
       {
            fprintf(stdout,"Invalid character(s) entered, please re-enter.\n");
            y=0;
       }
    }
    return(x);
}

int Empty()
{
    int clearr,n=0;
    do
    {
        n++;
    }while((clearr=fgetc(stdin))!= EOF && clearr !='\n'); // If EOF or '\n' is reached
                                                          // it ends, returning the 
                                                         //number of characters
    return(n);
}
```

If i then run the program and enter 2 or 2.2 etc, the number is accepted and returned.

If i enter 2a, or 2 a or 2 2 etc it always catches the space/letter/etc and forces a SINGLE loop to allow you to try and reenter a value

If, however if enter the offending item, i.e the a, first then an infinite loop occurs.

This does not make sense to me as from what i understand, when the `fgetc(stdin)` is called it MUST pull either a character or an `EOF` which would signify only one item has been entered, ending the loop.

Comment: How do you know it loops?

Comment: It prints f"Invalid character(s) entered, please re-enter.\n" infinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a test `if( A || B )`, if A is true, B is *not* evaluated.

So if `scanf("%lf",&x)!=1` is true, `Empty()` is not called and your loop continues forever.

One of the problems here is that you try to do several things at once, the advice would be:

- keep things simple
- no side effects

So 1) scan the input, 2) if it's ok move on, 3) if it's not flush and repeat.

Comment: Ok thank you that worked, however if i now put 2a it accepts the 2 and then moves on, ignoring the a, which i once again can't see why that would happen.

Comment: I figured this one out, it enters because both values are not true it is 1 and 0, so it does not fail the result

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a , `scanf("%lf",&x)` will give 0 and hence it never calls Empty.